# Error installing python preppy

Tags: python, package, virtualenv

When installing preppy in a virtualenv on my workstation (Ubuntu Linux) it works, but when installing it the same way on an instance of Amazon Linux I get an error like this:

```
(env)[ec2-user@server t]$ pip install preppy
Downloading/unpacking preppy
  Downloading preppy-2.3.2.tar.gz (42kB): 42kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy/setup.py) egg_info for package preppy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        import preppy
      File "/home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy/preppy.py", line 72, in <module>
        isPy3 = sys.version_info.major == 3
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy/setup.py", line 13, in <module>

    import preppy

  File "/home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy/preppy.py", line 72, in <module>

    isPy3 = sys.version_info.major == 3

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/ec2-user/t/env/build/preppy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ec2-user/.pip/pip.log
```

This hints at a problem when checking what the Python version is, but googling around did not help me this time.

I'm aware that python packages sometimes have dependencies on host software, eg to install psycopg2 I had to first install the Postgres development packages on the operating system.

So how do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ec2 instance needs to be running (at least) Python 2.7.

`sys.version_info` didn't become a named tuple until 2.7.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with whatever you're working on!